# ActiveRecord joins: integer columns converted to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model named Article, which I am joining with TwitterShare as shown below:

```
articles = Article.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN twitter_shares ON articles.id = twitter_shares.article_id").where("articles.id = ? or articles.id = ?", 27165, 5632).select("articles.id, twitter_shares.user_id")
```

When I get the articles back, and examine the Article model returned, it returns the user_id as a string, even though the column type in the twitter_shares table is an integer. Why is this? How can I make ActiveRecord return the integer column as an integer, not a string?

Comment: I would add that in case of handling lots of data it gets really nasty as to_i and to_f are slow operators. So, what can we do here?

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I bumped into the same problem in Rails 3.2.16, but it seems to appear when using PostreSQL as the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert the returned user_id with `.to_i` where you need it as integer?