# Wh is Rails API rendering integers as strings when using .joins(...)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a Rails API, and when I render a result of a query User.where(...) it returns integers and strings perfectly. But when I render the result of User.joins(:friends).where(...) it makes the non-primary key integers from the friends table strings. The integer strings from the users table are just fine, it only happens on fields that were joined.

If I can't figure this out, then everyone who consumes my API will have to do string->integer conversions before they compare values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you rendering: erb, jbuilder... ?

Comment: I'm doing something like this:         render :status => 200, :json => users

Comment: I've also used Rabl with the same result

Comment: This seems to be the exact same question asked differently. Doesn't seem to be a render issue, rather an ActiveRecord issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639344/activerecord-joins-integer-columns-converted-to-strings